# Hirerarchical side bar menu

Tags: plugin-recommendation, sidebar

i am new to wordpress and i have to show the my menus in side bar in hierarchial way 
like

```
Home page
    --menu1
    -------menu1-submenu1
    -------menu1-submenu2
    --menu2
    -------menu2-submenu1
    -------menu2-submenu2
```

and they should be collapsible in starting and when i click on main menu of it will show me the sub menus .

my test enviorment URL is http://178.236.226.168/reseller-hosting/

and the html who's copy i have to do in my menu is

http://servercentre.net/small-and-medium-business/email-and-apps/hosted-exchange-2010.html

any plugin who fullfill my requirement really very much help full to me.

and i already tried some plugin's like collapsing-pages.0.6.1.zip,gd-pages-navigator.zip,flexi-pages-widget.zip but none of them giving me that effect.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a plugin to do this, you can do it with `wp_nav_menu()` (and it's related functions) and CSS.  Specifically what you should be looking at is the `.current-page-ancestor` and `.menu-item-ancestor` to display (or not display) the desired links.

Comment: as i written in my question i am very new to wordpresss so can u please  help me where i have to made these changes ?

Comment: it can be done with any plugin so i dont have to write any code

Comment: If you already have the side menu setup, you can just modify it in `Appearance->Menus`

Comment: yah, i already done there but side menu appearing in a vertical straight line.i want to them be categorized and collapsible and expandable

Comment: Then modify the CSS...you might need some javascript too. If you are asking how to do the CSS, it is not an appropriate question for this site, as it does not deal with wordpress.

Comment: as you can see i have html in which its working fine , but i am not getting where to change in wordpress to work this.

Comment: Where the CSS is located?